# bash pattern replacement working on terminal but not working in script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I'm running into a weird issue when using bash pattern replacement. When running the following commands I would expect the same output:

```
% cat test.sh 
bash --version

VAR_FOO=masked::required::VALUE
VARIABLE_NAME=${VAR_FOO//(required|masked)::/}
echo $VARIABLE_NAME

% ./test.sh 
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
masked::required::VALUE

% bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
% VAR_FOO=masked::required::VALUE
% VARIABLE_NAME=${VAR_FOO//(required|masked)::/}
% echo $VARIABLE_NAME
VALUE
```

Instead the pattern replacement isn't working when running the command in a .sh file. As you can see it seems like it's using the same bash version. I'm at a loss to what's causing the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(For completeness: Running on macOS 11.5)

Comment: Your terminal is running zsh. No version of bash supports `(pattern|pattern)`.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. My mistake, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Also in `zsh`, executing a script without a shebang causes the script to be executed with `sh` (which happens to be `bash` on macOS). `bash --version` doesn't really tell you anything about what executes your script, only that you have version 3.2.57 installed on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash pattern matching is described in the manual at [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

In bash you'd have to do this:

```sh
shopt -s extglob       # enable "extended" patterns

VAR_FOO=masked::required::VALUE

# using `@(patt1|patt2|...)` to mean "match one of the following patterns"
# - replacing with "x" to show the replacements
VARIABLE_NAME=${VAR_FOO//@(required|masked)::/x}

declare -p VAR_FOO VARIABLE_NAME
```

outputs

```
declare -- VAR_FOO="masked::required::VALUE"
declare -- VARIABLE_NAME="xxVALUE"
```